# differences between 'weak' and 'unowned' references in vala?

Tags: weak-references, vala

What are the differences between weak and unowned references in Vala.

Based on what I've learned from Vala tutorials both weak and unowned references are not counted, and when the real instance goes out of scope they will refer to null(!!).

Why there should be tow distinct means for one reason?(if they do the same job)
If not, could someone give me a simple example to show why and when we have to use each of them?!

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7):

There is no difference between the two *right now*. The language developers chose two distinct keywords to indicate the possibility that there may be a difference *in the future*, see this quote from the [documentation](http://live.gnome.org/Vala/ReferenceHandling):

> At the moment weak and unowned can be used interchangeably. However, you should use weak only for breaking reference cycles and unowned only for ownership issues as described above.

Weak references are used, as far as I can see, on `GLib.Object` subclasses, and unowned references are used on non-reference-counted ("compact" in Vala terminology) classes imported from non-GObject C libraries. There are examples on the documentation page I linked to above.